# I can't figure out how to extend my Arch home partition into free space

Tags: arch-linux, partition, gparted

I'm trying to resize my home partition, but I can't figure out how to do so. Move/Resize doesn't let me move the bar, and there's no space to extend it to. I can't unmount it because it says it's busy.

I saw talk of moving partitions around to be adjacent to extend into the free space, but how would that work? I can't move the unallocated space, and wouldn't moving my home partition before the unallocated space screw stuff up?

[image]

Comment: You cannot have a partition in two places on a disk.  Well you actually can if you use LVM instead of plain partitioning, but nevertheless you will need to boot from something that is not using the partitions (e.g. a live system) before making any changes.

Comment: but a live system of arch can't use gparted, can it? can my windows partition do the copying necessary?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/182319/sixth and http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/182327/sixth.  You’ll then be able to comment on answers to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the figure, you can't move the last three partitions.  But you could *create* a new partition in the unallocated space, and copy your existing `/home` there, e.g., using rsync.

Once you've done that, you can free up the 23Gb on the end of the drive, making it (more) useful to extend your system disk.

Breaking it down a little:

- create a ***new*** `ext4` partition in the unallocated space (actually gparted makes a *partition*, you'll probably have to do a `mkfs.ext4` or something like that to make the *filesystem*).
- mount that temporarily (not as `/home`, but for example as `/mnt`)
- use rsync (as **root**) to copy the whole `/home` tree, e.g.,

  `rsync -va /home/ /mnt`
- modify your `/etc/fstab` to mount the new partition on `/home` (and a good idea to keep the old `/home` on a different path)
- reboot
- decommission the old partition after you're done verifying things, by unmounting it, removing the line from `/etc/fstab` and then deleting the partition with `gparted`.

Comment: Do I need to do any linking or mounting to make that work once I'd have copied over the files?  and then are you recommending I just add the 23 gb to the root partition? because, from what I've read, that seems a bit much.

Comment: I don't recommend copying files from a running system. If some files are modified during the copy, you could end up with an inconsistent state.

Comment: So then, in my fstab, I comment out the /home line, and duplicate it with the only change being the new UUID? so my new line looks like  

`UUID=288ff8b3-f800-41bd-badd-68a928ff515c       /home           ext4            rw,relatime,data=ordered        0 2`

Comment: It's `/home` (if you prefer running system applications from `/home`, that's your problem).

Comment: So what can I put for my new location on the old partition? i.e. what do I replace the old '/home' with? can it be anything?

Comment: See [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/) for example how to find a new UUID.

Answer (score 2):

A partition is a segment of the disk, not a combination of segments. Since the home partition is at the end of the disk, and the root partition is immediately before it, there's no room to extend the home partition.

You can extend mounted partitions, but not move mounted partitions around. So you should work from a live system.

You can move the home partition into the free space; then you'll be able to enlarge it to ~44GB. But rather than just move the partition, I recommend that you switch your Linux partitions to [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) (see also the [Archi wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM)). LVM is a partition system that's a lot more flexible than the basic MBR/UEFI system; its only downside is that it's specific to Linux, so it normally lives inside an MBR/UEFI partition. If you'd used LVM, you could have enlarged that home partition very easily.

From a live system:

1. Run `fdisk` to:

   1. Remove the swap partition. We'll re-create it afterwards.
   2. Create a partition of type “Linux LVM” in the free space. Give it the number 5.
2. Create an LVM physical volume on the new partition. An LVM physical volume is space on a disk for LVM partitions.

   ```
   pvcreate /dev/sda5
   ```
3. Create an LVM volume group. A volume group relates physical volumes (disk segments) to logical volumes (containers for a filesystem or swap space). Here `arch` is the name of the group, feel free to pick a different name.

   ```
   vgcreate arch /dev/sda5
   ```
4. Create logical volumes to move your root and home filesystems into LVM, and for the swap space. Make sure that the root and home volumes are at least as large as the existing filesystems. Beware that GParted is evil: it rounds filesystem sizes, so if you use what it displays, you risk losing a bit of data at the end, which could make the filesystem unrecoverable. Use the real size information.

   ```
   grep sda[67] /proc/partitions    # shows partition sizes in kB
   lvcreate -L "$(awk '$4=="sda6" {print $3}' /proc/partitions)k" -n root arch
   cat /dev/sda6 >/dev/arch/root
   lvcreate -L "$(awk '$4=="sda7" {print $3}' /proc/partitions)k" -n home arch
   cat /dev/sda7 >/dev/arch/home
   lvcreate -L 24g -n swap arch
   ```
5. Mount the new location of the home and root partitions, to make sure that the copy is fine.

   ```
   mkdir /media/root /media/home
   mount /dev/arch/root /media/root
   mount /dev/arch/home /media/home
   # Check that both filesystems look fine
   ```
6. Edit `/etc/fstab` and make sure that it's using valid references to your partitions. If you're using UUIDs or labels, you can keep using that. If you were using partition numbers, you must change that. You can use the LVM device locations, they're stable: `/dev/arch/root` and `/dev/arch/home`.
7. I don't know how Arch Linux sets up its booting system. On some distributions, you need to regenerate the second-stage bootloader and the initramfs to include LVM support. On Arch, it seems that [you need to add `lvm2` to `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` and regenerate the initramfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM#Add_lvm2_hook_to_mkinitcpio.conf_for_root_on_LVM).
8. You don't need the old space with the home and root partitions anymore. You can reuse them for LVM by creating an LVM physical volume in them (`pvcreate /dev/sda6 /dev/sda7`) and adding those physical volumes to the existing volume group (`vgextend arch /dev/sda6 /dev/sda7`). After that, if you ever want to extend your filesystems, you can call `lvextend` without worrying about location: it'll use free space anywhere in the volume group to extend the logical volume, then call `resize2fs` to enlarge the filesystem.